# App stops when opening second Activity with button

Tags: android

When I try to start a new Activity by clicking a button the App stops unexpectetly.

Before I just did it without the Accleration sensor and it worked perfectly fine but after adding it the problem that it stops after trying to start a new Activity appeared.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
    package com.example.accelerationint;



import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

TextView accel;
Sensor accelerometer;
SensorManager sm1;

Button btnSet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sm1 = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sm1.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm1.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    accel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAccCurrent);

    btnSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSet);

    btnSet.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    accel.setText("X:"+event.values[0]+"\nY:"+event.values[1]+"\nZ: "+event.values[2]); 



}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this , SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    finish();

}
}
```

My Second Activity:

```
     package com.example.accelerationint;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SettingsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnApply;

EditText editALimit , editDeltaT  , editTWait , editALow , editAIntermediate , editAHigh ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    editALimit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editALimit);
    editDeltaT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDeltaT);
    editTWait = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTWait);
    editALow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editALow);
    editAIntermediate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAIntermediate);
    editAHigh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAHigh);

    btnApply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSet);

    btnApply.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

And the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.accelerationint"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat errors:

```
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start activity          ComponentInfo{com.example.accelerationint/com.example.accelerationint.SettingsActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at com.example.accelerationint.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:33)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
    07-17 23:18:36.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5423):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: Downvoting because no research is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to unregister your sensor listener `onDestroy()`.

EDIT:  Now that I look at your stack trace, I suspect that there's no view in your settings layout with the ID `R.id.buttonSet`.  The crash happens in `SettingsActivity.onCreate()` and the only method there that depends on having a valid reference is where you set the click listener.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Seems a reasonable programming error when resources are not released. Also, upvote because of 'probable' ;)

Comment: I implemented:[ sm1.unregisterListener(this, accelerometer); ] in the onDestroy() method but it still stops. Did I do anything wrong?